# What does the phrase 'physics defying action' mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

I am reading the book about the Simpsons, and I am not sure what is the author trying to say in this sentence.

> 'Far more than in any previous year, Season 8 is littered with scenes and plots that involve the kind of **hyperkinetic cartoon violence and physics defying action** that is more usually associated with Warner Brothers and Hanna-Barbera.'

PS: can I replace the word 'hyperkinetic' by the word 'exaggerated'?

Comment: Someone forgot the hyphen... 'physics-defying'

Comment: I didn't know that. Even so, that don't do nothing for me. I'm still confused and don't understand this sentence.

Comment: Some physics-defying action: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gq_bjaI0NTo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Physics defying action* (as Tetsujin says, this is more properly written *physics-defying*) is action which defies physics: that is, it does not obey the laws of real-world physics.

*Exaggerated* captures a part of what is meant by *hyperkinetic*, but is not a good paraphrase. "Exaggerated violence" might be extreme in its effect, or motive, or means; "hyperkinetic violence" means violence expressed in extreme **motion**: perhaps unrealistic speed or suddenness, or change of direction.